# How To Capture and Repeat Voice with different voice modulation like Tom Cat app

Tags: android

i want to develop like a talking tom cat app in android,but i have no idea for this concept any one guide for me.first i need how to change voice with different modulation and repeat voice any one help with me any tutorial and any code with greatly appreciated...!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution? I looking for something like that too.

Answer (score 0):

don't know about the start recording and stop recording, but you can change the voice while playing, just use a `Sound Pool`.

```
 public final int play (int soundID, float leftVolume, float rightVolume, int priority, int loop, float rate)
```

For the sound to be heard like talking tom, set the rate between 1.0 to 2.0. This will make the sound appear to be faster.

For more information on Sound pool refer [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html)